# Retrieving Tags in Geoname XML in Python

Tags: python, minidom, geonames

I am looking to retrieve the timezoneId tag from the geoname api, by providing latitude and longitude.

http://api.geonames.org/timezone?lat=39.758720&lng=116.041420&username=demo

It is structured this way:

```
<geonames>
<timezone tzversion="tzdata2012c">
<countryCode>CN</countryCode>
<countryName>China</countryName>
<lat>39.75872</lat>
<lng>116.04142</lng>
<timezoneId>Asia/Shanghai</timezoneId>
<dstOffset>8.0</dstOffset>
<gmtOffset>8.0</gmtOffset>
<rawOffset>8.0</rawOffset>
<time>2012-07-21 13:13</time>
<sunrise>2012-07-22 05:05</sunrise>
<sunset>2012-07-22 19:38</sunset>
</timezone>
</geonames>
```

I am trying to get the element this way:

```
document=minidom.parseString(urllib2.urlopen(DATA_SRC).read())
el=document.getElementsByTagName("geonames")[0].getElementsByTagName("timezone")[0].getElementsByTagName("timezoneId")[0]
print el.firstChild.nodeValue
```

Apparently the getElementByTagName does not return any child... what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that you spelled it 'noveValue' in the last line.  Is that a typo or actual code?

If you want timezoneId, you can continue getElementsByTagName down the tree.

```
document=minidom.parseString(urllib2.urlopen(DATA_SRC).read())
el=document.getElementsByTagName("geonames")[0].getElementsByTagName("timezone")[0].getElementsByTagName("timezoneId")[0]
print el.firstChild.nodeValue
```

The reason your `el.firstChild.nodeValue` was returning nothing is because it has no text inside it, it was returning an empty string.  You needed to continue further down the tree to see the text node value of timezoneId.

Comment: The nodeValue was a typo, not the real code - just added it manually but corrected it.

Comment: Now, regarding your comment : you said I have to continue down the tree to see the text node value, but isnt it what I am actually doing when doing "getElementsByTagName("timezoneId")[0] ?

Comment: I didn't see the last bit "getElementsByTagName("timezoneId")[0]" there, I missed it; but yes - that should then work.  If you run urllib2.urlopen(DATA_SRC).read() on its own, does it return any XML?

Comment: Yes, urllib2.urlopen(DATA_SRC).read() returns the XML i copied in my question. SO something is going wrong with the getElementByTagName but I cannot figure what...

Comment: Actually the very first line does not start with <geonames> but with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 - Could that be the reason why this is not working ?

Comment: Problem solved. Indeed, the first line was causing the problem !